# React Native - Destructuring parameter item in renderItem FlatList attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, destructuring

I'm porting a ReactJS project over React Native, and I'm trying to learn Native's Components. I want to display a list/sequence of track cards after fetching their data from Musixmatch and Spotify.

In ReactJS, I would just render this:

**ReactJS**

```
return (
        <>
            <h1 id="top10tracksitalyheader">Top 10 popular tracks in Italy</h1>
            <div className="toptentracks">
                { topTenTracks.map((track) => {return <TrackPreview data={track.data} key={track.data.id} album={track.album}/>}) }
            </div>
        </>  
    );
```

**React Native**

```
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.topTenTracksTitle}>This is the TopTenTracks Component.</Text>
            <FlatList 
                data={topTenTracks}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.data.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <TrackPreview data={item.data} album={item.album} />
                )}
                horizontal
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator
                pagingEnabled
            />
        </View>
```

I'm definitely confused about that {item} destructuring in the renderItem function. I've read that the FlatLine is expecting an array as the data attribute, and topTenTracks is indeed an array, more precisely an array of objects. This of course makes no problem for the .map() method in the ReactJS code chunk.
But what about React Native's renderItem? I've read that it expects an Object as its function argument, and item is indeed an Object, since topTenTracks is an array of Objects.
Why is the destructuring needed then? Also, how does the destructuring know that it needs to extrapolate the item itself, if "item" is not a field of the Objects in topTenTracks?

I know this might be a dumb question, but I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `renderItem` looks like this:

```
renderItem({
  item: ItemT,
  index: number,
  separators: {
    highlight: () => void;
    unhighlight: () => void;
    updateProps: (select: 'leading' | 'trailing', newProps: any) => void;
  }
}): JSX.Element;
```

React Native calls `renderItem` with other pieces of data, not just the items in the array passed to the `data` prop. As a result, items inside the array passed to `FlatList`'s `data` prop is assigned on the `item` property of the object passed to each `renderItem` call. See [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).